# What does an 'at' @ sign mean in Julia?

Tags: syntax, julia

For example, here:

```
ys = lift(frequency, phase) do fr, ph
    @. 0.3 * sin(fr * xs - ph)
end
```

from [here](http://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/basic-tutorial.html#Plotting-Observables).

---

I am failing to interpret it as a [macro](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Basics) definition or call.

Answer (score 7):

TLDR: `@` invokes a macro. https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/

One of julia's best features in my opinion are it's macros. They allow you to easily write functions that manipulate source code. `@.` for example turns `0.3 * sin(fr * xs - ph)` into  `0.3 .* sin(fr .* xs - ph)`. Another common example is `@time` which roughly would translate the same expression to

```
t1=time()
0.3 * sin(fr * xs - ph)
println(time()-t1)
```

Note that neither of these are achievable by a function, since functions have their inputs evaluated before they run, while macros instead operate on the code itself.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is worth to add that it is easy to learn what `@.` does by invoking help. Press `?` then write `@.` and hit enter to get:

```
help?> @.
  @. expr

  Convert every function call or operator in expr into a "dot call" (e.g.
  convert f(x) to f.(x)), and convert every assignment in expr to a "dot
  assignment" (e.g. convert += to .+=).

  If you want to avoid adding dots for selected function calls in expr, splice
  those function calls in with $. For example, @. sqrt(abs($sort(x))) is
  equivalent to sqrt.(abs.(sort(x))) (no dot for sort).

  (@. is equivalent to a call to @__dot__.)

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> x = 1.0:3.0; y = similar(x);
  
  julia> @. y = x + 3 * sin(x)
  3-element Array{Float64,1}:
   3.5244129544236893
   4.727892280477045
   3.4233600241796016
```

where you also learn that `@.` is just a shorthand for `@__dot__`.

And if you want to find its definition write e.g.:

```
julia> @which @. 1
@__dot__(__source__::LineNumberNode, __module__::Module, x) in Base.Broadcast at broadcast.jl:1241
```

to get the exact information on location of its implementation or write `@edit @. 1` and it will get opened-up in your editor.

Above I have commented on how to learn what `@.` does and how it is implemented. If you want to learn what is the effect of `@.` (or any macro in general) you can use the `@macroexpand` macro. Therefore if you write e.g.:

```
julia> @macroexpand @. coalesce(sin(@view x[:, 1]), 0.0)
:(coalesce.(sin.(true && (view)(x, :, 1)), 0.0))
```

you can see how `@.` macro rewrites your original expression `coalesce(sin(x), 0.0)`. Note that in this case the expressions are not evaluated - you only get an equivalent expression with all macros removed.

If you wanted to see only `@.` macro expanded (assuming - as in an example above it is the outermost macro) then use:

```
julia> @macroexpand1 @. coalesce(sin(@view x[:, 1]), 0.0)
:(coalesce.(sin.(#= REPL[11]:1 =# @view(x[:, 1])), 0.0))
```

As you can see `@macroexpand1` is not recursive and only expanded the outermost macro and left `@view` macro untouched.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning `@macroexpand1`  also?

Comment: OK - I will add this. Actually I thought of including it in the comment but I did not to over-complicate the answer :).